# How to handle the dynamic cookies when crawling a website by python?

Tags: python, web, cookies, pycharm, web-crawler

I am a very beginner of Python. And I tried to crawl some product information from my [www.Alibaba.com](http://www.Alibaba.com) console. When I came to the visitor details page, I found the cookie changed every time when I clicked the search button. I found the cookie changed for each request. I can not crawl the data in the way I crawled from other pages where the cookies were fixed in a certain period.

After comparing the cookie data, I found here were only 3 key-value pairs were changed. I think those 3 values made me fail to crawl the data. So I want to know how to handle such situation.

Answer (score 0):

For python3 the [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) in the standard library can be configured to use an [http.cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html) `CookieJar` which will keep track of cookies within the client automatically.

You can set this up like this:

```
import http.cookiejar, urllib.request
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

If you're using pyhton2 then a similar approach works with `urllib`:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```